# Python termcolor as HEX

Tags: python, python-3.x, termcolor

How I can use python termcolor with HEX? I want make something such this:

```
print(colored('hello', HEX="#eb3434"))
```

Comment: Do you want to color text in terminal (as `termcolor` tag suggest) xor in GUI (as `tkinter` tag suggest)?

Comment: In terminal. Sorry tkinter was error (:

Comment: So, any ideas? (:

Comment: @Klovik8 For most terminals you can use [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) escape codes to do anything that you need. That includes colouring text, moving the cursor around, ...

Answer (score 0):

*In terminal*

Then take a look at [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) if external module is option. It works in many operating systems, it support named color, but I do not know if it does support CSS hex codes.

Comment: The colour in the terminal isn't really dependant on the OS. It is dependant on the terminal application itself. And how well it follows the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)